# How do I make the footer cover the whole width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

I would like the footer to cover the whole width of the screen. 
This is how it looks right now:
[Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGzpP.png)

I would appreciate help!

```
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="container">
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark" id="footer">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">&copy; X <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>. This website was made with Bootstrap.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: Take it out of the `container` or remove the margin from the container.

Answer (score 0):

Just take it out from the `.container`

```
<!-- Footer -->    
<footer class="py-5 bg-dark" id="footer">
  <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">&copy; X <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>. This website was made with Bootstrap.</p>
</footer>
```

or if you need `.container` inside a `footer`

```
<footer class="py-5 bg-dark" id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">&copy; X <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>. This website was made with Bootstrap.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put that container `div` tag inside `footer`

So that all the content of footer will be in container while the footer will be having 100% width

```
<footer class="py-5 bg-dark" id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">&copy; X <script>
      document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
    </script>. This website was made with Bootstrap.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```